# React Native difference between nested arrow function and normal arrow function

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

```
let arr;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  arr.push(
    <ListItem key={i}> // native-base component
      <Button
        onPress={this.pick(curJob, i)}>
      </Button>
    </ListItem>
  )
}


render(){
  return (
    { arr }
  )
}
```

In this code, what is the difference between the two functions?

Function 1.

```
pick = (job,index) => {
  console.log(job);
  console.log(index);
}
```

Function 2.

```
pick = (job,index) => () => {
  console.log(job);
  console.log(index);
}
```

I found that function 2 works fine but function 1 returns error (maximum call stack size exceeded) 
I wonder what is the difference between the two functions and if function1 can be called call-back function.

Comment: The second one is a function that returns another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is invalid.

The prototype of an arrow functions is the following :

```js
variableName = (arguments) => {
    Body
}
```

Your `onPress` should be : `onPress = {() => this.pick(curJob,i)}>`, otherwise, the function is called everytime a render happens, so always. With the `() =>` before, you are telling the program to run `this.pick` only onPress

Answer (score 0):

```
 pick = (job,index) => () => {
                console.log(job);
                console.log(index);
           }
```

this is just function returning a function its equal to

```
nestedfunc(job, index) => {
  console.log(job);
  console.log(index);
}


pick = (job,index) => nestedfunc(job,index);
```